# Word order: "10 minutes more" or "10 more minutes"?

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs, word-order

> - I'm still packing my clothes. I'll need 10 minutes more.
> - I'm still packing my clothes. I'll need 10 more minutes.

Are both grammatically correct?

Comment: I have closed this question due to lack of details. Either of these could be grammatically correct (or nonsensical, for that matter) depending on the context. In most cases, I think, they would convey a change in tone as opposed to a change in meaning, but asking such a vague and open-ended question really isn't fair to the community. Add a few examples showing how you might use the two phrases in a couple sentences, and then the question can be reopened.

Comment: Yes, both are grammatically correct.  The more common (unmarked) word order is "ten more minutes".

Comment: @user2246 Perhaps mentioning what made you speak that sentence will provide a more realistic context. Did anyone make a request? Somebody interrupted you from something? (Anyway both are grammatically correct as snailboat said.)

Comment: I think most native speakers would not use the future 'tense' here and would instead just say, "I need 10 more minutes."

Comment: I would say: _I need another 10 minutes_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're both correct. But "I need 10 more minutes" is probably more common. (There's no reason to make it progressive or conditional. The need is in the present.)